# Maximising the area of a triangle with its vertices on a parabola.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, analytic-geometry, area, maxima-minima

> Let $A\equiv (4,-4)$ and $B\equiv(9,6)$ be tw points on the parabola $y^2 = 4x$. Let $C$ be a point on the parabola between $A$ and $B$ such that the area of the triangle $\triangle ABC$ is maximal. What are the coordinates of $C$?

The  parametric coordinates of C are $(t^2 , 2t)$. Using [Shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula), I get the area of the triangle to be $5t^2 -5t$. But this has no global maximum? In this case, what shluld I do?

Comment: You could think geometrically, and show that the area is maximal when the tangent to the parabola at $C$ is parallel to $AB$, because that gives the largest height of the triangle (using $AB$ as base).

Comment: Also, your shoelace formula is wrong, because it's not zero when $C = A$ (at $t = -2$) or when $C = B$ (at $t = 3$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shoelace formula for the points $(4, -4), (9,6), (t^2, 2t)$ gives
$$
A = \frac12\left|4\cdot 6 + 9\cdot 2t + t^2\cdot (-4) - (-4)\cdot 9 - 6\cdot t^2 -
 2t\cdot 4  \right|\\
= \frac12|24 + 18t - 4t^2 + 36 - 6t^2 - 8t|\\
= |30 + 5t - 5t^2|
$$
Since we "[l]et $C$ be a moving point on the parabola between $A$ and $B$", that means that $t$ is between $-2$ (which makes $C = A$) and $3$ (which makes $C = B$). On this interval, $30 + 5t - 5t^2$ is positive, so we can drop the absolute value signs, and find a maximum at $t = 0.5$, which gives $C = (\frac14, 1)$ and area of $31.25$.

Comment: Great! I always struggle to decide the order of coordinates in the shoelace formula. How did you decide it?

Comment: @Abcd Does it matter in a triangle

Comment: @gilly There are definitely ways of multiplying pairs of coordinates that give the wrong answer, yes.

Comment: @Abcd It's a formula I've worked with a lot in the context of cross product of vectors, so I'm used to it, and have a pattern that in my head that I follow. Apart from that, the way I've done it here closely follows the order given on your wikipedia link. If I had followed the wikipedia formula exactly, the last half would've been $- 9\cdot (-4) - t^2 \cdot 6-
 4\cdot 2t$ instead.

Comment: @Arthur This doesn't work: https://imgur.com/a/HydqO . Why?

Comment: @Abcd It does work. You add all the down-right diagonals: $9\cdot2t+t^2\cdot (-4)+4\cdot 6$. Then you subtract all the down-left diagonals: $-6\cdot t^2-2t\cdot 4-(-4)\cdot 9$. What you get is exactly what I have in my first line, just in a slightly different order.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of $AB$ is $y=2x-12$.

Let $l||AB$.

We see that $S_{\Delta ABC}$ would be maximal for $C\in l$ and $l$ is a tangent line to the parabola.

Let $C\left(\frac{c^2}{4},c\right)$.

Thus, $yc=2\left(x+\frac{c^2}{4}\right)$ is an equation of the tangent line,

which gives $\frac{2}{c}=2$, $c=1$ and $C\left(\frac{1}{4},1\right)$.

Comment: @Abcd I mentioned it in a comment below your question, but the $C$ that gives the largest possible height must necessarily give a tangent that is parallel to $AB$.

Comment: I did not see it. Now I see it.